# Favicon is Not Visible on Website

Tags: favicon

I have the following code:

```
    <head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>EPDM Polymers | EPDM Rubber Granules | Poured-In-Place Rubber</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->

    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/BackToTop.jquery.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

However, The favicon is not showing up on www.epdmpolymers.com  I have the favicon.ico file in my images folder. Any ideas?

Comment: remove first link `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`  and for testing first clear all your browsing history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 links for favicon.ico, try removing the first link from your code. I guess it would work for you.

Or once again cross-check the path of the image, try using relative path to the file.
For example: If your image is in root/images folder, so use (/images/favicon.ico)

Comment: Do you have any idea why it doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox but does in Google Chrome?

Comment: There is no relation of browser here. It should work in every browser. You can check once again but before that clear all your cache and cookies from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite debugging methods is to download and use a favicon.ico file from a working site like http://www.google.com/favicon.ico

- If it works then the issue will be because of your file size or
  format.
- If it does not work then the issue will be either with the
  html tag.
- To rule out file permission issue try accessing your    favicon file
  directly using its url through the browser address bar.